# The Generated File By The Command Line Doesn't Exist

Tags: python, sox

I'm using SOX Command in Windows to Convert .wav files to a spectogram .png file, from the cmd directly it's working but in the python script it returns 1 but the image doesn't exist in the directory specified.

```
rootdir =r'C:\Users\Heba\output.wav'
wave_path = rootdir
wave_image_path = wave_path.replace(".wav", ".png").
cmdstring = 'sox "{}" -n spectrogram -r -o "{}"'.format(wave_path, wave_image_path)
subprocess.call(cmdstring, shell=True)
```

it doesn't provide any errors too, any help please?

Comment: Apparently there's no path specified so CWD is being used which is not what you expect. What is the value of `wave_image_path`?

Comment: Is sox's location in the PATH environment variable (i. e. can it be called from command line in an arbitrary directory)?

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski This is clearly shown in the code (and it is an absolute path).

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski The same Path as "wave_path" with replacement of ".wav" by ".png"

Comment: @MichaelButscher Yes i added it to the environment variables and it's working fine from the command line but in my python script it doesn't

Comment: You have a redundant dot at the end of the line 2: `wave_image_path = wave_path.replace(".wav", ".png").`. Is the dot in your script or it's just a typo?

Comment: @Trilliput No it's a typo in my post